# Kibana UI is not up but the container is up and running

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana-7

I am upgrading Elasticsearch as well as Kibana from 5.6.14 to 7.4.2

My ES is up and running

Hitting http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v in browser 
gives me below output

```
health status index                    uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   .kibana_task_manager_1   joI0GprPTJaJX0h7CcEi8w   1   0          2            0     12.5kb         12.5kb
green  open   .apm-agent-configuration XJ2AF4NUQKivJ9gMZOHOfA   1   0          0            0       283b           283b
green  open   .kibana_2                2H66ezpOR7W5tTas3oxH1g   1   0          4            0     18.3kb         18.3kb
green  open   .kibana_1                IOEPzbfUSQO7u3sN-S7p6A   1   0          2            0      9.4kb          9.4kb
```

Contents of elasticsearch.yml

```
http.host: 0.0.0.0
# Uncomment the following lines for a production cluster deployment
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
node.name: 'node-1'
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```

Tried to start the kibana container, Container is up but in UI I am getting
 {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"} or sometimes kibana is not ready to start message.

This is my kibana.yml

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.basePath: "/clog"
server.rewriteBasePath: false
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
xpack.security.enabled: false
kibana.index: ".kibana"
```

I get following in logs

```
log   [06:41:45.744] [info][status][plugin:oss_telemetry@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:45.747] [info][status][plugin:file_upload@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [06:41:45.752] [warning][encrypted_saved_objects] Generating a random key for xpack.encrypted_saved_objects.encryptionKey. To be able to decrypt encrypted saved objects attributes after restart, please set xpack.encrypted_saved_objects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [06:41:45.755] [info][status][plugin:encrypted_saved_objects@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:45.787] [info][status][plugin:snapshot_restore@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
  log   [06:41:45.837] [info][status][plugin:kibana_react@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:45.840] [info][status][plugin:region_map@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:45.993] [info][status][plugin:timelion@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.000] [info][status][plugin:ui_metric@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.005] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.009] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.013] [info][status][plugin:table_vis@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.018] [info][status][plugin:tagcloud@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.021] [info][status][plugin:vega@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:46.027] [warning][browser-driver][reporting] Enabling the Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection.
  log   [06:41:46.056] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.081] [info][license][xpack] Imported license information from Elasticsearch for the [data] cluster: mode: basic | status: active
  log   [06:41:47.089] [info][status][plugin:xpack_main@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.089] [info][status][plugin:graph@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.091] [info][status][plugin:searchprofiler@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.092] [info][status][plugin:ml@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.092] [info][status][plugin:tilemap@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.093] [info][status][plugin:watcher@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.094] [info][status][plugin:grokdebugger@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.094] [info][status][plugin:logstash@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.095] [info][status][plugin:beats_management@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.096] [info][status][plugin:index_management@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.097] [info][status][plugin:index_lifecycle_management@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.097] [info][status][plugin:rollup@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.098] [info][status][plugin:remote_clusters@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.099] [info][status][plugin:cross_cluster_replication@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.099] [info][status][plugin:file_upload@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.100] [info][status][plugin:snapshot_restore@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:41:47.101] [info][kibana-monitoring][monitoring] Monitoring status upload endpoint is not enabled in Elasticsearch:Monitoring stats collection is stopped
  log   [06:41:47.127] [info][status][plugin:maps@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:42:06.495] [warning][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [06:42:06.513] [info][status][plugin:reporting@7.4.2] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
  log   [06:42:06.683] [info][listening] Server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
  log   [06:42:06.717] [info][server][Kibana][http] http server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601
  log   [06:42:06.725] [info][status][plugin:spaces@7.4.2] Status changed from yellow to green - Ready
  log   [06:42:06.732] [warning][telemetry] Error scheduling task, received [task:oss_telemetry-vis_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [5]): [version_conflict_engine_exception] [task:oss_telemetry-vis_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [5]), with { index_uuid="joI0GprPTJaJX0h7CcEi8w" & shard="0" & index=".kibana_task_manager_1" }
  log   [06:42:06.733] [warning][maps] Error scheduling telemetry task, received [task:Maps-maps_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [5]): [version_conflict_engine_exception] [task:Maps-maps_telemetry]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [5]), with { index_uuid="joI0GprPTJaJX0h7CcEi8w" & shard="0" & index=".kibana_task_manager_1" }
```

I used node:10.15.2-alpine image on top of it adding kibana7.4.2 using kibana-7.4.2-linux-x86_64.
Also I tried using docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.4.2 still  getting same error log.

Note we dont have licence to use x-pack So we need to disable it where ever it is used. I donot know what is missed out. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Not sure if it will take you anywhere but perhaps logging.verbose: true will give more insight. I have experienced Kibana take a very long time to accept requests.

Comment: see https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/kibana-config-version-conflict/1386/4

Comment: Thanks for the help but logging.verbose: true is not working.

Comment: https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/kibana-config-version-conflict/1386/4  also doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I think I have faced similar issues. Can you try edit `elasticsearch.yml` like so?

```sh
http.host: 0.0.0.0
# Uncomment the following lines for a production cluster deployment
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
node.name: 'node-1'
discovery.type=single-node
xpack.ml.enabled: false
```